# Can't build react native app with expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

**Problem**
I made an app with react native (create react native app) and I am now trying to build it with expo. When I run "sudo exp build:android", I get two warnings (picture included) and then when the app starts building online it says that it had an error building the app. I am super confused, because I can run the app fine, it just won't build.

**app.json**

```
  {
       "expo": {
        "name": "Phoenix",
        "icon": "./CandidtwoImages/Phoenixlogo.png",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "slug": "exp.io/@giise/candidtwo",
        "sdkVersion": "21.0.0",
        "ios": {
          "bundleIdentifier": "com.giise.phoenix"
        },
        "android": {
          "package": "com.giise.phoenix"
        }
       }
     }
```

**Warning messages**[image: warning message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slug should be just `candidtwo` -- the slug refers to the last part of your url when published, for example, with the url `https://expo.io/@giise/candidtwo`, `candidtwo` is the slug.

Comment: Thanks! This got rid of the slug warning